# iPhone Objective-C convert String to NSDate *special case

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know this kind of questions have been asked a thousand times on this forum, but I have a slightly special case which I could really use some help with.

I have an NSString *expirationDate with the value = "2010-06-23 04:28:59.341818"

I need to convert to an NSDate object and compare against the current Date/Time. Can someone kindly explain how to do this?

I'm assuming its going to use some kind of NSDateFormatter object with YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS... but how do i handle the remaining decimal portion?

Comment: May have found solution:

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
 
NSDate *dates = [dateFormat dateFromString:expirationDate];
NSLog(@"ExpirationDate=%@",dates);

which returns: 2010-07-24 13:57:02 -0700

Not quite the accuracy I wanted

Comment: If you have an answer you can post it as one... It does not need to be a comment. Just to let you know :).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];        
[formatter setDateFormat:@"SSSSSS"];
NSString *dateInMyFormat = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];



value of - dateInMyFormat: 648000
```